# creating a timer clock with java frame i.e Jframe

Tags: java, timer, jframe

I am stuck at a point where I need a Timer which displays some time remaining when i click a button on the Jframe. But the timer frame should be a different frame and should be unclosable. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> different frame and should be unclosable.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

The same can be done for a JDialog.

In both cases the close button will appear on the window, it just won't do anything.

Using a dialog is better than a frame because in general applications should only have a single JFrame and the child dialogs for other windows.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an undecorated non-modal JDialog?

Comment: But can that modaless JDialog can be made un closable, i.e close button is not operational.